# How to save to MySQL from Spark Streaming

Tags: java, mysql, json, apache-spark, spark-streaming

This question might be independent from the Spark Streaming framework, but I might as well mention that I'm using it.

I am running a very simple Spark Streaming program in which I have a DStream in which each RDD is a JSON line with an 'id','value' and 'timestamp'. Each time that I receive a Json line, I store the value of these attributes in static java objects.
So, something like this:

```
//Outside of main()
...
private static String idpoint;
private static String value;

//Inside main()
...
//Inside RDD function

String idpoint=id;
String  value=c;
Date date= new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
String formatedDate= sdf.format(date);

String final=idpoint+","+"value";
```

My goal now is to store each line in a table from my MySQL database, one JSON line per table line.

I already created a method to download the JDBC drive outside the main():

```
public static void sqlcode()
    {
        try
        {
            // Step 1: "Load" the JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.imaginary.sql.msql.MsqlDriver");

            // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database
            String url = "myjdbc string";

            Connection conn =   
DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("D'oh! Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But if I declare this method in main(), it keeps reopening the connection to the database, since in Spark Streaming the main() method basicaly works like a while loop.
So how can I save these java objects to a MySQL table?
Hope I wasn't too confusing.
Thank you.

Comment: Either get the database connection before entering the stream callback or instrument your try catch code with a finally statement where you close your database connection and thus release resources

Comment: have you considered a singleton approach?

Comment: @mark91 I am pretty new to Java programming and never heard of the concept of singleton. I will research. How exactly do you think it can help me?

Comment: Singleton is a programming pattern which let's you have a single instance of a class which is crated the first time it is requested and then when the other requests occurs the previously created instance is returned. It is often used for DB connections, since it avoids to create more than one connection to a DB, by reusing always the same one.

Comment: Look at here for reference and examples: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-918906

Comment: Could you add the rest of the code? Using global mutable variables will *NOT* work in spark streaming.